# Calling Factory/Function From String

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am reading a config file which contains a mapping of Angular Factories/Function names. The Factory/Function names are stores as strings in the mapping. I am wondering how would I be able to execute the Factory/Function I have read from config?

None of these factories are accessible on `window` otherwise I could call `window[factory][functionName]()`.

Would I have to resort to something like:

```
var factory;
var factoryName = getFactory(config.sendTelemetry);

if (factoryName === 'TelemetryFactory') {
    factory = TelemetryFactory;
} else if (factoryName === 'DebugFactory') {
    factory = DebugFactory;
}

factory[functionName]();
```

Sample config file:

```
// Sample config file
var config = {
    'sendTelemetry': {
        'factory': 'TelemetryFactory',
        'functionName': 'sendTelemetry'
    },
    'logDebug': {
        'factory': 'DebugFactory',
        'functionName': 'logDebug'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the functions are just normally scoped functions, you can do a one-off creation of a lookup map from name to function reference to avoid the long `switch` statement:

```
var funcMap = {
    TelemetryFactory: TelemetryFactory,
    DebugFactory: DebugFactory
};
```

or to avoid the (potentially error-prone) repetition, by using each function's `.name` property and constructing the map from an array of function references:

```
// build lookup map
var funcs = [ TelemetryFactory, DebugFactory ];
var funcMap = {};
funcs.forEach(function(f) {
    funcMap[f.name] = f;
});
```

In ES6 it becomes even simpler, because ES6 has an object literal syntax where you can pass the name of a variable (or function) and it automatically creates a key with that variable's name and value:

```
let funcMap = { TelemetryFactory, DebugFactory };
```

Whichever of the three methods above you use to build the map, dispatch is then a trivial operation via the map:

```
funcMap[factoryName]();
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you'd need to evaluate the strings first:

`eval(factory[functionName])();`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Correct; I just realised that the factory needs evaluating as well.

Comment: Any way to do it without `eval()`?

Comment: @Jon yeah - see the other answer ;)